# Basic Insert / Update Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Running MySQL Database and all tables are InnoDB

Every evening we have a list of the top offending slow queries emailed to us via a batch script.

In this list are two queries an insert and an update.

The insert script logs page views for a user.  To make this more efficient we will only write an insert once for a user in a session.  So we store the pages viewed in a session and do an in_array on page load.  If the page is not in the array than we write an insert.

This table has 700,000+ records with the only index being the primary key (id).

The insert into this table looks like this:

```
insert into page_views (user_id,page_name,created)
values ('4','Test Page','2013-08-13 10:44:21')
```

This query shows up on our slow query log as taking a while.  My question is how can this be made more efficient.  I feel as if this is part of the reason our database is running slower.

---

We also have an update query that runs on an InnoDB table with about 14,000+ records.  The update happens when a user views a specific record for the first time and we set a field titled viewed='YES'.

```
update test_table set viewed='YES' where id=55
```

This update is showing up on the slow query log as well.  This table "test_table" has about (5) different indexes on it.

---

#

Output from slow query log

Count         : 165  (0.35%)
Time          : 2252.210041 s total, 13.649758 s avg, 2.026723 s to 313.311842 s max  (8.96%)
  95% of Time : 1181.480258 s total, 7.573591 s avg, 2.026723 s to 49.99961 s max
Lock Time (s) : 12.722 ms total, 77  avg, 38  to 233  max  (0.04%)
  95% of Lock : 11.681 ms total, 75  avg, 38  to 84 max
Rows sent     : 0 avg, 0 to 0 max  (0.00%)
Rows examined : 0 avg, 0 to 0 max  (0.00%)
Database      :
Users         :
        XXXXX@localhost  : 100.00% (165) of query, 99.76% (46921) of all users

Query abstract:
SET timestamp=N; INSERT INTO page_views (user_id, page_name, created) VALUES ('S', 'S', 'S')1;

The table structure for page_views

id (int) primary key
page_name (varchar(255)) 
created datetime

What are my options for speeding up simple insert and updates on very large tables?

Comment: You should post your table schema (output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`).

Comment: Could you give more information about table structure (show create table statement), and it the server correcly configurd to handle innodb? innodb needs a good config or it is trouble.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your application uses a great many of these two statements, and the ones you have showed us are examples. Is that correct?  Can you show us the `EXPLAIN` output from these queries?

Comment: EXPLAIN does not work on UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the huge number of rows in your table and rows should be added/modified regularly in those tables. I'd suggest to execute following query first and see the execution time for the queries you have mentioned:

analyze table page_views;

analyze table test_table;

Above commands will not take much time, should be executed with 5/10 secs.

If you can afford little longer maintenance time(depends on the size of table):

optimize table page_views;

optimize table test_table;

If you see performance gain, I also would like to inform that you can configure cron job which executes analyze daily and optimize weekly/monthly.